# Запрос MySQL, извлекающий все категории

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется такая структура БД.

Таблицы:

- **`cats_arts`** - категории статей
- **`sites`** - сайты где должны быть размещены статьи
- **`articles`** - сами статьи

Поля таблицы **`cats_arts`**: *`id`*, *`name`*
Поля таблицы **`sites`**: *`url`*, *`id`*
Поля таблицы **`articles`**: *`id`*, *`site_id`*, *`category(id категории)`* ...

Мне нужен запрос, чтобы вызволить все категории, используемые на сайте, у меня получился такой запрос:

```
$site = "http://test.com/";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT c.id,c.name FROM cats_arts c LEFT JOIN sites a ON a.url='$site' LEFT JOIN articles b ON b.site_id=a.id WHERE c.id=b.category");
```

Но почему-то такой запрос выводит по нескольку раз одну и туже категорию( Помогите пож-та...

**P.S.** Правильно SQL запрос, или всё-таки MySQL?

Comment: Да не работает хтмл здесь)) Я у вас уже раза 3 видел эти <br>

Два переноса ставьте

Comment: вспомнил, надо 2 пробела)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT...

Comment: Эта штука не исключает неправильность запроса, ведь нагрузка на mysql больше из-за этого, представте будет 2к статей, и вместо двух категорий выведет 2к категорий, после этого отсеит лишнее, но всёравно спасибо, на крайняк пригодиться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$site = "http://test.com/";
$res = mysql_query("
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name
FROM cats_arts AS c
  JOIN articles AS a ON (a.category = c.id)
  JOIN sites AS s ON (s.id = a.site_id)
WHERE 
  s.url='$site'
");
```

Если я правильно понял вашу мешанину из букв (типа articles - b, sites - a), то что-то подобное должно работать. То есть мы выбираем категории, которые являются родительскими для статей, которые прилинкованы к сайтам, и выбираем из них те, которые относятся к сайту с url='$site'.

Comment: Всёравно вместо 2-х категорий, выводит эти 2 по три раза( Связь в том что статей 6 шт., поэтому для него и надо 6шт. вывести категорий( Если нет из этого выхода, то как можно сделать через  GROUP BY?

Comment: @mctrane, так добавьте сюда DISTINCT и будет то что вам нужно, думаю) Или в конце `GROUP BY c.id`.