# Sql запрос и обработка на php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется 3 таблички.
Задание, типы заданий (категории грубо, их может быть несколько к одному заданию) и связывающая их табличка.

**table1**
id, user_id, price

**table2**
id, name

**table3**
id, table1_id, table2_id

Как построить запрос, что бы в одной обработке массива while через php вывести табличку заданий и в одной из ячеек все установленные категории.
То есть вывод table1 со всеми параметрами + все записи в table3 относящиеся к определенному заданию.

По сути можно 2 запроса, цикл в цикле, но это дико грузит. Помооогиите составить грамотный запрос.

Comment: в простейшем варианте group_concat()

Comment: Через group_concat не выйдет. Мне в дальнейшем нужно ещё будет вывести красиво эти категории и работать с ними. Основная проблема - это составить правильный SQL запрос для вывода всех заданий и их категорий.

Comment: ну, с одной стороны, можно также сгруппировать и айдишники, но это и правда будет уже извращение

Comment: Если одним запросом, то только так https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/nested_array

Comment: Извращение я уже реализовал) Запрос - вывод через цикл и тут ещё запрос и вывод через цикл. Вот похожий вопрос, но у меня чуть другая задача - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103047/Запрос-mysql-извлекающий-все-категории , но таблички идентичны

Comment: посеиу не выйдет group_concat() - group_concat(id), group_concat(name) - .будут все данные второй таблицы

Comment: Окей, допустим есть возможность вывести все категории вместе одной строкой, в дальнейшем я там уже разрулю всё это дело. Не мог бы помочь с составлением запроса?

Comment: в каком смысле - "разрулю"? это ты про explode() что ли?

Comment: Ага. С запросом всё никак не выходит, не хватает знаний при работе с операторами(

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS 'category' FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B ON A.id = B.table1_id
JOIN table3 C ON B.table3_id = C.id ORDER BY A.id DESC

и дальше через explode работаю в php с нужными категориями. Спасибо!